# Error with objective c functions deprecated

Tags: objective-c

I'm trying to edit my source code on Xcode, but I keep getting an error.

**Code:**

```
// Present the mail composition interface.
[self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
```

> ERROR: 'presentModalViewController:animated:' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 6.0

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Look at the docs for that method and lookup what deprecated means.

Comment: How about reading the documentation! [Deprecated UIViewController Methods](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html)

Answer (score 1):

Typically, using deprecated features in any programming language may not work or may result in malfunctioning software.

Wikipedia defines deprecated as:

> Deprecation is an attribute applied to a computer software feature,
>   characteristic, or practice to indicate that it should be avoided
>   (often because it is being superseded).

In short, you shouldn't be using `presentModalViewController:animated:`, and that's why you're getting the error.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deprecation